# Using Moq how do you verify function was called without specifying parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, moq

Sometimes I want to just verify that a function was called rather than have to test the function was called with specific parameters.

The reason for this that there is a complex object being passed in as a parameter, but the later call inside that function makes a database fetch.  Since this will be mocked, it will just have nulls & 0s.

I just want to verify the call without testing against the passed in parameters.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find the [following blog post](http://salmontech.blogspot.com/2009/11/moq-ignoring-arguments.html) useful. Quote:

```
myMockedClass.Verify(
    x => x.Connect(It.IsAny<MyArgumentType>())
);
```